# Equivalent of C# 'readonly' for an MS SQL column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, default-value, alter-table

Imagine there is a `Price` column in `Products` table, and the price may change.
I'm fine with it changing but **I want to store the original `Price` value in another column**.

Is there any automatic way MS SQL  server may do this?

Can I do this using **Default Value** field?
Do I have to declare a trigger?

#### Update

I tried to use `Price` to simplify the question but it looks like this provoked "use separate table" type of answers.
I'm sorry for the confusion I caused.

In the real world, **I need to store a foreign key ID and I'm 100% I only need *current* and *original* values**.

#### Update 2

I got a little confused by the different approaches suggested so please let me explain the situation again.

Imaginary `Products` table has three fields: `ID`, `Price` and `OriginalPrice`.
I want to **set`OriginalPrice` to `Price` value on any insert**.

Sometimes it is a single product that gets created from code. Sometimes there are thousands of products created by a single `insert` from a stored procedure so I want to handle these properly as well.

**Once `OriginalPrice` has been set, I never intend to update it.**

Hope my question is clearer now.
Thanks for your effort.

#### Final Update

I want to thank everyone, particularly [@gbn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27535/gbn), for their help.
Although I posted [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913991/eqivalent-of-c-readonly-for-an-ms-sql-column/6914530#6914530), it is largely based on [@gbn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913991/eqivalent-of-c-readonly-for-an-ms-sql-column/6914195#6914195) and his further suggestions. His answer is also more complete, therefore I mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your update, let's assume you have only old and new values.

Let's ignore if the same update happens in quick succession because of a client-code bug and that you aren't interested in history (other answers)

You can use a trigger or a stored procedure.

Personally, I'd use a stored proc to provide a basic bit of control. And then no direct UPDATE permissions are needed, which means you have read only *unless* via your code.

```
  CREATE PROC etc
  ...
  UPDATE
    MyTable
  SET
    OldPrice = Price,
    Price = @NewPrice,
    UpdatedBy = (variable or default)
    UpdatedWhen = DEFAULT --you have a DEFAULT right?
  WHERE
    PKCol = @SomeID
    AND --provide some modicum of logic to trap useless updates
    Price <> @NewPrice;
```

A trigger would be similar but you need to have a JOIN with the INSERTED and DELETED tables
What if someone updates OldPrice directly?

```
  UPDATE
    T
  SET
    OldPrice = D.Price
  FROM
    Mytable T
    JOIN
    INSERTED I ON T.PKCol = I.PKCol
    JOIN
    DELETED D ON T.PKCol = D.PKCol
  WHERE
    T.Price <> I.Price;
```

Now do you see why you got jumped on...?

After question edit, for *INSERT* only

```
  UPDATE
    T
  SET
    OriginalPrice = I.Price
  FROM
    Mytable T
    JOIN
    INSERTED I ON T.PKCol = I.PKCol
```

But if all INSERTs happen via stored procedure I'd set it there though....

Comment: Yes I do! Cheers gbn. I think I may have misunderstood how a trigger works. I thought a trigger would only ever contain 1 record in the `Inserted` table as the trigger would be ran multiple times if multiple records were updated. This is not the case it seems?

Comment: I edited my question to make it more clear.. Can you please take a look? I highly appreciate your time and effort, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your second sample. If I go with the trigger way, do I need to make it `for insert`? Is this right?

Comment: The reason I'm confused is I thought `for insert` triggers don't have a `deleted` table.

Comment: @Dan Abramov: now you've stated "price at insert, will never be updated", it is more clear. Your original implied "current" and "previous" (which is Mitch's answer)

Comment: Nah, it's "current" and "original" :-). But you're right I made a mess out of a simple question. Yeah, I only want to set `OriginalPrice` during the **first insert** and I want it to work both with stored procedure batch insert and from code (single insert). That's why I didn't place the logic in batch insert procedure itself. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Can you please take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913991/eqivalent-of-c-readonly-for-an-ms-sql-column/6914530#6914530)? I tried to follow your advice and created an `after insert` trigger but I'm not 100% sure I did it right.

Answer (score 2):

There is no readonly attribute for a SQL Server table column.  BUT you could implement the functionality you describe using a trigger (and restricting permissions)

**Except**, it is not the best way to solve the problem.  Instead treat the price as Type 2 ['slowly changing dimension'.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension)  This involves having a 'ValidTo' column (os 'StartDate' and 'EndDate' columns), and closing off a record:

```
Supplier_Key    Supplier_Code   Supplier_Name   Supplier_State  Start_Date  End_Date
123           ABC             Acme Supply Co    CA            01-Jan-2000   21-Dec-2004
124           ABC             Acme Supply Co    IL            22-Dec-2004
```

If you do go the route of a trigger (I suggest you use SCD type 2), make sure it can handle multiple rows: [Multirow Considerations for DML Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190752.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your input in this thread. Can you please take a look at the newest update I posted? I think I finally made my question clear (I hope so..)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend storing your price in a seperate table called `Prices`, with the columns `Price` and `Date`.

Then whenever the price is updated, `INSERT` a new record into the `Prices` table. Then when you need to know the current price, you can pull from there.

---

However, if you wish to update an `OriginalPrice` column automatically, you could add a `TRIGGER` to the table to do this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I should've clarified—`Price` was just an example, in my actual problem I need to store an original foreign key ID, and it's certain I only need to have access to current and original values.

Comment: Ah in that case, see my part of the answer regarding triggers

Comment: I think this is better handled as a Type 2 'slowly changing dimension'

Comment: @Curt: that cursor code is very flawed: ALL cursors must be able to handle multiple rows.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat - Can you please explain further or provide an article I could reference? This is the way I've used triggers the past few years so would be interested in knowing what Ive done wrong.

Comment: @Curt: if that's the case, you have been writing broken code, I'm afraid. Any trigger must be able to handle multiple rows.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190752.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with, with a heavy help from [@gbn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913991/eqivalent-of-c-readonly-for-an-ms-sql-column/6914195#6914195), [@Mitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913991/eqivalent-of-c-readonly-for-an-ms-sql-column/6914056#6914056) and [@Curt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913991/eqivalent-of-c-readonly-for-an-ms-sql-column/6914051#6914051):

```
create trigger TRG_Products_Price_I --common-ish naming style
    on dbo.Products after insert as
begin
    set nocount on

        update m
        set OriginalPrice = i.Price 
        from Products p
        join inserted i on p.ID = i.ID

end
```

I tried to follow [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190752.aspx) as well.
Thanks to everyone!

Comment: You only need one condition for any number of rows. And naming

Comment: Thanks. I'll test it soon. One more question: does it mean I have to allow nulls for `OriginalPrice`? Obviously the trigger runs *after* the insert, although I'm sure in the end the value is set..

Comment: Either set a default on the column (say zero) or make it NULL. Personally, I'd make it NULL